# Create Anonymous Links to SharePoint Online Documents using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I want to programmatically (c# csom) create anonymous view links to SharePoint online documents to enable guest users to View the documents without requiring them to sign in. After extensive research, I found these two snippets code.

This supposedly creates the link:

```
var newRoleAssignment = new UserRoleAssignment() { Role = Role.View, UserId = "" };

DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo(
                                ctx,
                                item["FileRef"].ToString(),
                                new List<UserRoleAssignment>() { newRoleAssignment },
                                validateExistingPermissions: true,
                                additiveMode: true,
                                sendServerManagedNotification: true,
                                customMessage: null,
                                includeAnonymousLinksInNotification: true);
```

And this, retrieves the link from the document:

```
var objSharingInfo = ObjectSharingInformation.GetObjectSharingInformation(
                            ctx, item, false, true, false, true, true, true, true);
                    ctx.Load(objSharingInfo);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    //objSharingInfo.AnonymousEditLink 
                    orderDets = objSharingInfo.AnonymousViewLink;
```

The problem with the first snippet is that I don't know which UserID to pass. I tried with an empty string and with my account's ID and in both cases when loading the objSharingInfo (in the second snippet) I am getting an Exception with a message of "Unknown Error".

When I load the objSharingInfo on other items, independently to Snippet 1, on documents whose guest link would already have been manually created from SharePoint: Snippet 2 works and I can extract the link from objSharingInfo.

Any help would be appreciated - or else maybe there are any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate the anonymous link, you can use the below code:

```
string link = context.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/Documents/sample.docx",ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View);
```

To share the document, you can use the below code:

```
SharingResult result = context.Web.ShareDocument("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/Documents/sample.docx", "someone@example.com", ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View,true, "Doc shared programmatically");
```

[External sharing API for SharePoint and OneDrive for Business](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/10/02/external-sharing-api-for-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business/)